# set a storagePid of pw_comments

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to set a storage PID where pw_comments also looks for comments instead only on the page where pw_comments is inserted? 
Setting persistence.storagePid in Typoscript didn't help...

Background: I'm migrating comments from another extension to pw_comments but there the comments are stored mostly all in one folder. All the comments are belonging to news records. To figure out for any comment, which is the detail page where the news will be displayed, seems quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set/override the Storage Page where pw_comment should look for comments:

```
plugin.tx_pwcomments.settings.storagePid = 123
```

A possibility to look in several folders is not given.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as in controller of pw_comments all pids are referenced to $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id. Thats what I can see there but I hoped I am wrong

Comment: According to source code, there is this: `$this->commentStorageUid = is_numeric($this->settings['storagePid']) ? $this->settings['storagePid'] : $this->pageUid;`

So just if _plugin.tx_pwcomments.settings.storagePid_ is not numeric, it should take the actual page uid.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [EntryUid setting](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/pw_comments/Configuration/EntryUids/Index.html) of pw_comments. Usually pw_comments works on page base.

But for EXT:news e.g. the detail page of any news is always the same and comments are stored in same folder/pid.

This option allows you to define a GET parameter (e.g. tx_news_pi1[news]) to be respected as separator for comments in same sys_folder.

So each time you are on news with e.g. uid=1, you just get the comments, because in comment record the field "entry_uid" has the value "1".

Here you'll find an example of how to configure typoscript: https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-pw_comments/wiki#How-to-use-pw_comments-with-other-extensions

Because the GET parameter is configurable, you can use pw_comments with any TYPO3 extension. Limitation: just one plugin per page.

Comment: The general setup works fine. But I do not want to store the comments on the same page where the detailview of a news is. I want a sperate folder. setting plugin.tx_pwcomments.settings.storagePid does not help

Comment: Okay. Just set `settings.storagePid` instead of `peristence.storagePid` like Dennis described in his answer.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I figured out that in CommentController in initializeAction the pid for all actions is set:  $this->pageUid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id So it will not be requested if another setting exists somewhere